# Insert header to table

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have a list and I want to insert each element as header for each column in row 1.

```
    For i = 0 To 11 Step 1
        Cells(1 & i).Value = titles(i)
    Next i
```

However, I get my headers offset to the right by 10 when I run it:

[image]

Any idea how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how that even runs, you have i = 0 at the first iteration, there is no column 0 in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see the issue now.
You have `cells(1 & i)` that translates to `cells(10)` meaning column 10.

What you should have is `cells(1, i)`, notice the comma.
But that gives you column 0 as I wrote in the comment above so you need to make it:

```
    For i = 0 To 11 Step 1
        Cells(1, i + 1).Value = titles(i)
    Next i
```